# How to force a generator in a GAN to explore?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have a questions on GAN's. If I train a GAN a valid generator could be a constant mapping (just maps everything to the same output, which lies in the "true" domain) and the loss would be around 0 since it is not possible for the discriminator to distinguish. How could I force the generator to "explore" the output space? Example: If I train a GAN on MNIST it could technically happen that my generator only generates one shape of a "2" but I want it to predict different kinds of 2's and all other numbers 0,1, ...., 9.

Thanks! 
Tim